# NSTimer in AppDelegate does not update UILabel in UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, uilabel, nstimer, appdelegate

My goal is to start a timer in the app delegate and use it to call methods in other view controllers. When these methods are called they will update the text of the UILabel. I'm performing the method on the main thread but I can't figure out why the UILabel is not being updated. I know the method in the view controller is being called but the UILabel doesn't get updated. I also verified the IBOutlet connection in Interface Builder. I am using storyboard to lay out my views and attach the view controllers to those views.  What am I doing wrong?

In my AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "GreyViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (nonatomic) int counter;
@property (strong, nonatomic) GreyViewController *greyClass;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    NSTimer *timer;
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(performOnMain)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];

    return YES;
}

- (GreyViewController *)greyClass {
    if (!_greyClass) {
        _greyClass = [[GreyViewController alloc] init];
    }

    return _greyClass;
}

- (void)performOnMain {
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateLabel) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}

- (void)updateLabel {

    self.counter++;
    NSLog(@"appdelegate counter %i", self.counter);

    [self.greyClass updateGreyLabel:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", self.counter]];
}

@end
```

The GreyViewController.h is:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GreyViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *greyString;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *greyLabel;

- (void)updateGreyLabel:(NSString *)string;

@end
```

The method in my GreyViewController.m:

```
- (void)updateGreyLabel:(NSString *)string {

    self.greyLabel.text = string;
    NSLog(@"greyviewcontroller string %@", string);
}
```

Comment: call `[self greyClass];` method before staring your timer in Appdelegate, as you might not be able to access the object of `GreyViewController` there because it seems its not initialized yet.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara calling `self greyClass` in the app delegate does not work

Comment: it should be working, there is no reason it dont work.!! on more thing if you want to refer variable with `self` then synthesize it dont forget

Comment: @DipenPanchasara You don't need to manually synthesize `@property` anymore. It is automatically done for you by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call:

```
GreyViewController *greyClass = [[GreyViewController alloc] init];
```

in your "`updateLabel`" method (i.e. every two seconds) you're instantiating a new GreyViewController.  It's very likely you do ***not*** want to do that.

Instead, instantiate/create it once (or create it in your storyboard or XIB file) and the update the label which is connected to an outlet.

Comment: Edited the code in my AppDelegate to take care of the `alloc` and `init`. But it still doesn't fix my original problem.

Comment: That's because the "`greyLabel`" property in your GreyViewController is NULL.

Comment: But from the NSLog in the `updateGreyLabel` I know the string is being updated with the timer. So why would that same string not work for the label?

Comment: insert this line as the first line in your "`updateGreyLabel`" method: "`if(self.greyLabel == NULL) NSLog( @"self.greyLabel is NULL" ) else self.greyLabel.text = string;`".  I'm 95% certain you haven't set up your greyLabel property with the actual UILabel object.

Comment: the UILabel is indeed NULL, how do i fix this?

Comment: figure out how to connect your property to an outlet (are you creating the label in a storyboard or xib file?) or connect your property to the UILabel that you created programmatically.

Comment: The label is dragged into the view in storyboard. I added the GreyViewController.h code in my question (see above).